# How to see the config values set via the cypress plugin

Tags: testing, cypress

I just started to learn cypress. I'm having a hard time understanding how plugins work.

In the docs regarding `cypress/plugins/index.js` file they say

> Inside of this file, you will export a function. Cypress will call
>   this function, pass you the project’s configuration, and enable you to
>   bind to the events exposed.

I have my `config.json` and `config.env.json` set up.
So in my plugin's `index.js` file, I want to see what config contains:

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
 console.log('config', config)
}
```

But when I run the test, nothing logs in the console. I've tried restarting the cypress, it didn't help.

I want to override some of the configs like they do in the docs https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/configuration-api.html#Usage.

So when does this file actually executes and how I can see what's in the config argument?

Thanks.

Comment: Ok, finally figured this out, so this file actually logs to the terminal instead of the browser console.

Comment: Also it can be seen in the Settigns tab of the Cypress app.

Comment: Hi, was there any solution to this? I ran into the same situation. I need to see values from my config.env.json in plugins/index.js